# How do i get row counts of Zend_Paginator object?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-paginator

I am using `Zend_Pagintor` class with `Zend_Db_Table_Abstract` .

`Zend_Pagintor` has a `count()` method but it always returns 1!

How do i get row counts?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can use:

```
$paginator->getTotalItemCount();
```

Comment: Inside the view partial for the paginator you can use `$this->totalItemCount`.

Answer (score 27):

Pick the right one for your needs:

- `count` returns the number of pages.
- `getAbsoluteItemNumber` returns the absolute item number for the specified item.
- `getCurrentItemCount` returns the number of items for the current page.
- `getItemCount` returns the number of items in a collection.
- `getItemCountPerPage` returns the number of items per page.
- `getTotalItemCount` returns the total number of items available.

You are probably looking for `getCurrentItemCount`  or `getTotalItemCount`

Check the API Docs for more details: http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/1.12